# How to use order_by when using group_by in Dajngo-orm, and take out all fields

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-orm

I used Django-orm,postgresql, Is it possible to query by group_by and order_by?

**this table**

```
| id | b_id | others |

| 1 | 2 | hh |
| 2 | 2 | hhh |
| 3 | 6 | h |
| 4 | 7 | hi |
| 5 | 7 | i |
```

**I want the query result to be like this**

```
| id | b_id | others |

| 1 | 2 | hh |
| 3 | 6 | h |
| 4 | 7 | hi |

or

| id | b_id | others |

| 4 | 7 | hi |
| 3 | 6 | h |
| 1 | 2 | hh |
```

**I tried**

```
Table.objects.annotate(count=Count('b_id')).values('b_id', 'id', 'others')
Table.objects.values('b_id', 'id', 'others').annotate(count=Count('b_id'))

Table.objects.extra(order_by=['id']).values('b_id','id', 'others')
```

Comment: I can:  Table.objects.filter(b_id__in=(i for i in range(20)); then use python;But it's not good if there is a lot of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try window function and subquery in the following way:

```py
from django.db.models import Window, F, Subquery, Count
from django.db.models.functions import FirstValue

queryset = A.objects.annotate(count=Count('b_id')).filter(pk__in=Subquery(
    A.objects.annotate(
        first_id=Window(expression=FirstValue('id'), partition_by=[F('b_id')]), order_by=F('id'))
        .values('first_id')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
result = Table.objects
    .values('b_id')
    .annotate(count=Count('b_id'))
```

Comment: thanks, but,I want `values` to take out `others`.  if so: `result = Table.objects.values('b_id', 'others').annotate(count=Count('b_id'))`,   `others` in group by， I just wish `b_id` was in group by